# Xamarin Forms - Button Behaviors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button behavior where i am doing some entry validations in it.

```
       protected override void OnAttachedTo(Button bindable)
        {
            bindable.Clicked += ButtonClicked;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

        void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // View Entry validations are performed here and change the color of Entry
        }
```

Also, I have binded Button Click Command in ViewModel.

**Issue:** ViewModel Command executes first and then Button Behavior Click event executes.    Is there a way to reverse the execution (ie.  Execute Behavior event first and then Button event)

**Why I need this?** It creates an issue if I set a entry property in ViewModel, It replaces it in Button Behavior.

Comment: A suggestion would be to trigger the vm command in the button clicked code instead. That way you ensure the correct flow sequence.

Comment: That is fine.  But for this issue, Do i need to get rid of behavior?